# Html Modal display image without stretching

Tags: html, css, image, modal-dialog

I use modal in html to display images, something similar to facebook's image display in messenger. I set the height of an image on a big screen to 90%, but if image is small, it gets stretched. On Mobile screens, it is setfor image to take 100% width of the screen and height is automatically adjusted, but if image is not very wide, it gets stretched. I want the image to be displayed in its natural size, but not higher than 90% on computer screen, and not wider than 100% on mobile screen. I tried with max-height and max-width, but it still stretched my picture.

Help is very appreciated!

I have this code for my modal
Html:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('imgmodal');
var img = document.getElementById('picture');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");
var download = document.getElementById('download-link');
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  download.href = this.src;
}
var span = document.getElementById("close");
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* exam_img */

#imgmodal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
}


/* Add Animation */

.content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    /* I want image to be vertically centered on smaller screens)*/
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    height: auto;
  }
  #close {
    top: 2px;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  #imgmodal {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  #caption {
    top: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="exam_li">
  <img id="picture" src="https://gapanalysis.usgs.gov/padus/files/2011/07/MT_GlacierNP500px-200x200.jpg" alt="Slika Testa" width="60" height="60" class="img-resposive exam-img">
</li>

<div id="imgmodal">
  <div id="caption">
    <a id="download-link" download>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>
      <a id="download-link" download></a>
  </div>
  <span id="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="content" id="img">
</div>
```

Comment: use width:auto for natural size

Comment: but then, if image is wider than size of the screen, it will not fit in the screen